# Issue while sending messages in loop to windows rabbitmq broker

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

**My Setup**

- I have a situation where i am sending some 15 messages in a loop from one machine to another machine via rabbitmq.
- There is **NAT setup** between sending and recieving machine.
- I am using spring rabbitmq for all rabbitmq operations.
- On the receiving machine, i am losing 2 messages **sometimes** which is never received  even after waiting for a long time.
- And also i don't see any messages accumulated in the queue (in both sending machine and receiving machine).
- And also there is only listener for the queue in the receiving machine.

**My Question**

- if i send messages in a loop to rabbitmq, is there any chance that it rejects some messages if it cant handle? The overall size of 15 messages in close to 8mb.

I don't see any exceptions even after i perform send message to rabbitmq.

**SENDING MACHINE CODE**

```
@Override
    public boolean send(final Message message, final String routingKey)
            throws SinecnmsMessagingException {
        private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = null;
        rabbitTemplate.send(routingKey, message);

    }
```

**RECIEVING MACHINE CODE**

```
<rabbit:listener-container
            connection-factory="connectionFactory">
            <rabbit:listener ref="onMessageCommand"
                queue-names="TestQueue" />
        </rabbit:listener-container>
        <bean id="onMessageCommand"
            class="com.test.OnMessageListner">
            <property name="callBackObject" ref="callbackEvent" />
            <property name="template" ref="amqpTemplate" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="callbackEvent" class="com.test.SettingsListener"></bean>
```

OnMessageListner implements MessageListener.

In SettingsListener class, i recieve the messages. This is working fine for all me in other code that i have developed. Only in this use case which i have mentioned, i am observing this issue.

Comment: Can you indicate the exchange type used in your configuration? If the type is not fanout, an unexpected routing key would be an obvious cause for the issue you describe.

Comment: All the messages are to the same queue. Routing key should not be the problem as other messges are going properly.And its topic exchange. This issue is intermittent.. Not always its observed.

Comment: in a standard setup, topic exchange means that if the routing key provided in some of the messages is not matching the binding between the exchange and the queue, the message is simply dropped. so I maintain my comment, this could be an obvious cause for the issue. Check your code to make sure you always put the same routing key in your message.

Comment: You should always show code and configuration. You can enable publisher confirms and returns to see the results of message publication - see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#template-confirms).

Comment: @GaryRussell added the code and configuration in the question.

Comment: Yes. i can implement publisher confirms and check. So does it mean that publisher confirms concept was introduced because some times rabbitmq may "reject/not accept" messages. With publisher confirms we can know if the first message was recieved by rabbitmq broker and then  send the second message. Can we conclude this?

Comment: And one important thing to observe here is that this issue is observed only in NAT environment. Otherwise its all fine.

Answer (score 0):

> So does it mean that publisher confirms concept was introduced because some times rabbitmq may "reject/not accept" messages. With publisher confirms we can know if the first message was recieved by rabbitmq broker and then send the second message.
>
> Can we conclude this?

No you cannot; waiting for each confirmation would slow down the publishing; confirms are designed so you send a bunch of messages and then wait for the confirms.

It was not `>introduced because sometimes rabbitmq may "reject/not accept" messages`; publishing with RabbitMQ is asynchronous; so a publish is generally successful - but anything can happen between sending the message and it arriving at the broker - if the connection is lost, the client is told, but that's too late for the publisher since he has already completed successfully.

NAT should make no difference but, perhaps, some flaky network router might be the problem.

You can use a network monitor (e.g. WireShark) to see what's happening.